# Blank Compare in Visual Studio 2013 Update 5

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a problem in Visual Studio 2013 (Update 5), when opening a project development on another machine, using the same version, Visual Studio marks all the files as containing differences, however when checking each file "Compare with Unmodified ", all files are blank, meaning no difference whatsoever.

If I select the "Undo" option in the project, close the project and open it again the problem does not happen.

The big problem is when I actually get changes made in my project, checking file by file will stretch a great deal of time.

Has anyone ever had a problem like this?

[image: Solution Explorer with markings of differences]

[image: No show difference in files]

Comment: Just as an addendum, you _can_ show the whitespace changes by clicking the "=" like button in the Diff toolbar. Maybe you can recognize what people did wrong then. I guess someone set his editor to use tabs while others use spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I know that can cause this behavior:

1. Your machine and/or the TFS Server is configured to enforce FIPS compliance which invalidates the hashing algorithm used to calculate differences. If this is the case, then all machines connecting to the TFS server and the server itself must be configured to enforce FIPS compliance, otherwise the hashes will be out of sync and all files will be marked changed.
2. There are whitespace changes, some plugin may be changing all line-endings from windows to linux or vice versa. Or doing the same with tabs and spaces. Your diff settings may be ignoring whitespace differences, so even though the files are different, they're the same according to the merge tool. You can configure whitespace checking using the <kbd>=</kbd> button on the diff toolbar.
3. You're using server workspaces and something or someone has removed the read-only bit from your files. Choosing "Go Offline" and then "Go Online" from the <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Source Control</kbd> menu should trigger a full compare of your local version against the server to restore sanity.

As a workaround, you can select "Undo Unchanged" from the Source Control Explorer or from the commandline (if you have the [Visual Studio TFS Power Tools 2015 installed](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)).